# A Remark on the definition of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subset\mathbb C$ be a connected open set,  a function $f$ defined on a subset $U$ of $D$ and with value in $\mathbb C$ is meromorphic on $D$ if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $P(f)=D\setminus U$ is a set of poles
2. $P(f)$ is **discrete** in $D$
3. $f$ is holomorphic on $U$

---

About the condition $2$ I don't understand if it should be:

2'. $P(f)$ is **closed and discrete** in $D$

Which of them is the right (most used) definition?

**edit:** For me $U$ is discrete in $D$ if every point of $U$ is isolated in $D$

Comment: It's a matter of terminology. A set being **discrete in** $D$ is often defined such that the set is discrete in the subspace topology, and closed. Namely "$A$ is discrete in $D$ if every $z \in D$ has a neighbourhood $W$ such that $W\cap A$ is finite".

Comment: And in complex analysis, *discrete* is often defined/meant to be **closed and discrete**. So in this case: Meromorphic functions should have a closed and discrete set of poles.

Comment: Practically the set of poles doesn't have any limit point in $D$. Is This  the aim of the definition?

Comment: Yes, the set of poles mustn't have an accumulation point in $D$.

Answer (score 2):

A discrete subset $F$ of a topological space $X$ is closed as well, since every $x\not\in F$ is not a limit point of $F$, and hence there is an open $U\subset X$, with $x\in U$ and $U\cap F=\varnothing$, which implies that $X\smallsetminus F$ is open.

Note that the poles cannot have a limit point in the domain of a complex function, but the can very well have a limit point in $\mathbb C$. For example, 
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/z)},
$$
has poles at $z=1/k$, for all $k\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}$. But $z=0$ is not a pole as it is not an isolated singularity. In particular, $f$ is meromorphic in $D=\mathbb C\smallsetminus\{0\}$ but not in $\mathbb C$.

Hence, although the poles do have a limit point, namely $z=0$, this limit point does not belong to $D$. So the poles do not have a limit point in $D$.

Comment: $A=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\,:\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is discrete in $\mathbb C$ but not closed in $\mathbb C$. The point $0$ is a limit point for $A$ but $0\notin A$.

Comment: @Galoisfan: Your set $A$ IS NOT discrete in $\mathbb C$, as every neighborhood of $z=0$ contains infinitely many elements of $A$. It is however discrete in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\{0\}$!

Comment: I use this definition of discreteness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point